# How does the libhugetlbfs library replace the memory allocation process with huge pages?

Tags: linker, malloc, shared-libraries, libc, ld-preload

According to [the document](https://github.com/libhugetlbfs/libhugetlbfs/blob/master/HOWTO), "libhugetlbfs can be used to make an existing application use hugepages for all its malloc() calls". And it is done through `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable.

> LD_PRELOAD=libhugetlbfs.so HUGETLB_MORECORE=yes ./a.out

According to [this article](https://catonmat.net/simple-ld-preload-tutorial), this is done by using `LD_PRELOAD` to override dynamically linked functions with the same name. But I couldn't find a function named `malloc` in the source code of libhugetlbfs (https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Alibhugetlbfs%2Flibhugetlbfs+malloc&type=code&p=1).

**How does it hook and override the origin `malloc`?**